# 'Have not' or 'can not'

Tags: tenses

If I lost my keys and I am trying to find them.

Which of the following would I say:

> 1. 'I haven't found my keys'
> 2. 'I can't find my keys'?

I hardly ever hear *'I haven't found keys'*, except if you put *'yet'* in the end. Otherwise it just sounds broken to me.

Answer (score 1):

“I cannot find my keys” means whoever is speaking physically does not have the ability to find their keys. “I have not found my keys” meant whoever is speaking has not obtained their keys at that current moment. I personally hear “I can’t find my keys” more often, but I believe “I haven’t found my keys” is more correct. Either way, if you are speaking in a casual environment, people will normally know what you mean either way.

See: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can

https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/

Comment: can not is cannot. in fact, here. :)

Comment: Both sentences are OK, but are slightly different in meaning.  To me, "I can't find my keys" doesn't mean I don't have the ability to find them, but rather that I'm looking for them right now (and/or have been looking for them for a short while) but haven't found them yet.  If I say "I haven't found my keys", the implication is that I've been looking for them for some time, but unsuccessfully.  "I can't find my keys" is more informal.

Comment: "can't" is often used figuratively like this, often in cases where you haven't been able to succeed and have given up. Once you give up, haven't becomes can't.